# Include the specified words in the html tag using php preg_replace

Tags: php

I have a words in array like :

```
// Array Words
$words = array("Tebrikler","congratulations","felicitaciones");

// The Text is:

$text = 'Hello brother, your child was born. Congratulations.';
```

// So need to fined the array words in the $text and make it in a div like the follow

```
Hellow brother, your child was born. <div class="cong">Congratulatons.</div>
```

In other words, we can find the specified words and get them into the div, like the example.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Would the CSS class used in the `<div>` always be `cong`, or could it depend on the particular keyword which were matched?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The class name can be different like for tebrikler `class="teb"` for felicitaciones `class="fel"` ect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `preg_replace`:

```
$text = 'Hello brother, your child was born. Congratulations.';
echo $text . "\n";
$words = array("Tebrikler","congratulations","felicitaciones");
$classes = array();
$classes["Tebrikler"] = "teb";
$classes["congratulations"] = "cong";
$classes["felicitaciones"] = "fel";
$get_css = 
$pattern = "/\b(" . implode('|', $words) . ")\b/i";
$text = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
    function ($matches) use ($classes) {
    $css = $classes[strtolower($matches[1])];
    return "<div class=\"" . $css . "\">$1</div>";
},
      $text);
echo $text;
```

This prints:

```
Hello brother, your child was born. Congratulations.
Hello brother, your child was born. <div class="cong">Congratulations</div>.
```

The strategy here is to first collapse your array of search terms into a regex alternation, becoming the following regex pattern:

```
\b(Tebrikler|congratulations|felicitaciones)\b
```

That is, we capture one of the above keywords, in case insensitive mode, and then replace with the term surrounded by the `<div>` tag.  The CSS class is obtained by doing a lookup of the keyword against an associative array.

**Edit:**

To address the comment by @KIKOSoftware, we can first use `preg_quote` on the keyword terms to escape any characters which might have a special meaning in regex:

```
$text = 'Hello brother, your child was born. Congratulations.';
$words = array("Tebrikler","congratulations","felicitaciones");
$words = array_map('preg_quote', $words);
$pattern = "/\b(" . implode('|', $words) . ")\b/i";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, "<div class=\"cong\">$1</div>", $text);
```

Comment: This will work with alphabetic words, but what if the words contain characters that will have a special meaning in the regex pattern?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware We can use `preg_quote` around the terms in the alternation to handle this edge case.  Let me edit my question.

Comment: Is the class name always "cong"?

Comment: @KoalaYeung The class name can be different like for tebrikler `class="teb"` for felicitaciones `class="fel"` ect. Thanks for your question.

Comment: @KoalaYeung I have addressed your comment in my updated answer, so this question is now completed.